# Spree - puzzled about ViewContext module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, spree

```
module Spree
  module ViewContext

    def self.context=(context)
      @context = context
    end

    def self.context
      @context
    end

    def view_context
      super.tap do |context|
        Spree::ViewContext.context = context
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can any kind soul please help enlighten me on the above codes from spree under lib/spree/i18n/base.rb? How do I evaluate “def self.context=(context)”? What is the ViewContext module purpose and use cases? Thanks in advance.